# How to know that a ring has a maximal ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I am new to the study of Abstract Algebra, how do I know if a ring $X$ of even integers contains a maximal ideal $Y$ such that the quotient $X/Y$ is not a field?

Comment: Consider the subring $4\mathbb{Z}$, the set of all integers multiple of 4.

Answer (score 3):

Let $R$ be the ring of even integers.

Let $M$ be the set of multiples of $4$.

Then $M$ is a maximal ideal of $R$, but $R/M$ is a two-element ring with no multiplicative identity, hence is not a field.